# MSTest code coverage file is too big, How to selectively generate code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, code-coverage, emma

I have  an MSTest code coverage setup in my visual studio project. However, when the code coverage runs, it generates a coverage file (data. coverage) that is too big. The reason being it scans for all the dlls, third party libraries. My project has some C++ solution and it generates code coverage for all the methods in the header files. Note that in my testsetting (local.testsettings, which is the currently active one) I have selected only a single xyz.dll (the one I want to get code coverage). However, the final code coverage contains code coverage information which xyz.dll depends on. How to configure, MSTest such that I don’t get code coverage beyond the boundaries of xyz.dll?
Note: Having a big data.coverage file cause issues when I try to generate xml reports using Hudson emma plugging. The final xml is about 750MB

Answer (score 0):

How a test coverage tool represents the data it records (probe locations, probe hits) obviously makes a difference in manageability of the collected test coverage data.

I can't speak to how MS encodes this data, but it is clear you aren't happy with the result.
 I will agree that 750Mb of output seems a bit over the top.

It may be the problem is you are simply getting every method/function instrumented when you
only want the DLL instrumented.   I suggest you look for a switch to control what is instrumented.  I can't help you further with the MS tool.

Our [C++ Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CppTestCoverage.html) will let you specify *just* the files you want instrumented.  It does produce a probe location file with one entry per probe, but its size is proportional to the amount of code instrumented, and it isn't a bulky XML file.  A million lines of instrumented code produces a probe location file of a few megabytes.  At execution time, you produce probe hit data; that exported is measured in bytes plural barely for each probe in the worst case, and is much smaller if your coverage is low or high.   For the same million lines, I'd expect this to be another megabyte.

It is likely a bit more effort to configure our tool to instrument a DLL; MS has the advantage of controlling the compiler and we do not.   That seems like a small price to get a usable answer.